# Question about the topology of a tangent bundle

Tags: general-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am reading Loring Tu's book about manifold. He defines the topology of a tangent bundle in the following way:

Given a smooth manifold $M$ of dimension $n$. For each chart $(U,\phi)$, we define $TU=\bigcup_{p\in U}T_pM$, where $T_pM$ is the tangent space at the point $p$. $\phi$ induces a bijection $\tilde \phi:TU\rightarrow \phi(U)\times \mathbb{R}^n$ and a topology $\tau_1$ on $TU$: a set $A\subset TU$ is open iff $\tilde \phi(A)$ is open. Define
$$\mathcal B=\bigcup_{\alpha}\{A|A\text{ open in }TU_\alpha, U_\alpha \text{ a coordinate open set in }M\}.$$
It can be shown that $\mathcal B$ is a basis, so it induces a topology $\tau_2$ on the tangent bundle $TM$. I believe the subspace topology of $\tau_2$ on $TU$ is the same as $\tau_1$ for all coordinate open set $U$ (I have this belief because I need to use this fact in order to prove that $\tau_2$ is second countable). Clearly the subspace topology of $\tau_2$ is finer than $\tau_1$, but I am having trouble proving the other direction. May someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. In the following paragraphs, for any chart $(U,\phi)$, whenever I say that "a set is open in $TU$", I mean that this set is open in the topology induced by $\tilde \phi$. We can first prove the following lemma:

Lemma: If $(U,\phi)$ and $(V,\psi)$ are two charts, then $TU\cap TV=T(U\cap V)$ is open in $TU$.

Proof: Since $(U\cap V,\phi|_{U\cap V})$ is a chart, $\tilde \phi(T(U\cap V))=\phi(U\cap V)\times \mathbb{R}^n$, which is an open subset of $\phi(U)\times \mathbb{R}^n$. Therefore, $T(U\cap V)$ is open in $TU$.

Now we prove that the topology induced by $\tilde \phi$ on $TU$ is finer than the subspace topology $TU$ inherits from $TM$. Given a set $C$ that is open in $TM$. Our goal is to show that $C\cap TU$ is open in $TU$. $C\cap TU$ is open in $TM$ because both $C$ and $TU$ are open in $TM$, which means that for every $x\in C\cap TU$, there exists a set $A$ such that $x\in A\subset C\cap TU$ and $A$ is open in $TU_\alpha$ (where $U_\alpha$ is a coordinate open set). $A$ is then an open subset of $TU\cap TU_\alpha$ because $A=A\cap(TU\cap TU_\alpha)$. By the lemma above, $TU\cap TU_\alpha$ is open in $TU$, so $A$ is also open in $TU$. This suggests that $C\cap TU$ is open.

Comment: I think you need to be a little more careful. A priori there are multiple topologies on $TU \cap TU_\alpha$, one as a subspace of $TU$ and one as a subspace of $TU_\alpha$. I would strengthen your lemma to say that these two are equivalent (to show this you should need to use that the derivative of $\psi \circ \phi^{-1}$ is a linear isomorphism, hence a homeomorphism). I think then the rest of the argument goes through (where you use the above fact in passing between the two corresponding meanings of "$A$ is open in $TU \cap TU_\alpha$").